# How can i perform Bird Eye view in Opencv

Tags: opencv, perspective

I want to implement bird eye view in opencv. I know this can be done by using perspective function but i couldn't get this kind of output with roof view
[image: img]

Any sample code to implement this as i am a beginner in opencv

Comment: A quick google search returns [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/). SO is not a tutorial or "provide sample code" site. It is a question and answer site.

Comment: I want the bird view using simple perspective it crop down my image area. Picture 3 has bird view and also no area is cropped.

Comment: Alright, provide the code you are testing, your input images and the bits that are giving you trouble and we will start from there.

Comment: with perspective transform you can warp one plane (e.g. the image) to another plane (e.g. a 2D ground plane map). You wont know anything about 3D objects projected to one of the planes, so "strange" visual effects can occur. Basically think about it as if all the things in the first image would be flat, lying on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

As the result you got is not what you're looking for, I'd say it's not possible to get the bird eye view of your image with just that image. You would need more data, for example, what the top of the objects look like.

Also, Opencv has no way of knowing which parts of the objects *(like the people's shoes)* should be hidden after warping, like each person on the street could as well as be paint smeared on the streets; there's just not enough data.